# Something like an FULL OUTER JOIN but only first match

Tags: sql, join, mariadb

I am working on MariaDB 10.1.12.

First let's see the table "prod_line_state" :

```
   id   |      timestamp      | state
---------------------------------------
 CHxxx  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |   0
 CHxxx  | 2016-07-07 16:18:49 |   1
 CHxxx  | 2016-07-07 16:19:00 |   0
 CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |   0
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:28:08 |   0
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:23 |   1
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:28 |   0
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:32 |   1
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:39 |   0
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 17:22:55 |   1
```

And I want this :

```
   id   |      StartedAt      |      StoppedAt      
---------------------------------------
 CHxxx  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 CHxxx  | 2016-07-07 16:18:49  | 2016-07-07 16:19:00
 CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2016-07-07 16:28:08
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:23  | 2016-07-07 16:29:28
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:32  | 2016-07-07 16:29:39
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 17:22:55  | 3000-01-01 00:00:00
```

"2000-01-01 00:00:00" and "3000-01-01 00:00:00" are fake date. This mean, there is no start logged or there is no stop logged.

For this I did the following query, witch is ugly but I don't know how to do it better :

```
SELECT id, Timestamp as StartedAt, IFNULL((SELECT Timestamp
                                           FROM prod_line_state
                                           WHERE State = 0 AND started.id = prod_line_state.id AND prod_line_state.Timestamp > started.Timestamp
                                           ORDER BY Timestamp ASC
                                           LIMIT 1), '3000-1-1 00:00:00') as StoppedAt
FROM prod_line_state started
WHERE State <> 0
UNION
SELECT id, IFNULL((SELECT Timestamp
                   FROM prod_line_state
                   WHERE State <> 0 AND stopped.id = prod_line_state.id AND prod_line_state.Timestamp < stopped.Timestamp
                   ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
                   LIMIT 1), '2000-1-1 00:00:00') as StartedAt, Timestamp as StoppedAt
FROM prod_line_state stopped
WHERE State = 0
ORDER BY id, startedAt, stoppedAt
```

So I search a better way to do it. Any Idea?

Comment: Where does CHvvv come from in your sample data?  I don't follow the logic for generating the desired results.  Can you explain how they are calculated?

Comment: Sorry for the CHvvv it is CHxxx. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       IF(state = 0, MAX(timestamp), NULL) AS StartedAt,
       IF(state = 1, MAX(timestamp), NULL) AS StoppedAt
    FROM ( SELECT
                @seq := @seq + IF(id != @prev_id OR state = 0, 1, 0) AS seq,
                id, state, timestamp,
                @prev_id := id AS junk
            FROM ( SELECT @prev_id := '', @seq := 0 ) AS init
            JOIN prod_line_state
            ORDER BY id, timestamp
         ) AS a
    GROUP BY  seq
    ORDER BY  seq
```

If that doesn't come close, give me the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERTs` for your test case.

Comment: Hi, I can t execute your query, looks like it is not MariaDB compatible.

Comment: I had a syntax error.  (I have not checked whether it works correctly.)

Comment: The result of your query is not good :


       id   |      StartedAt      |      StoppedAt      
    ---------------------------------------
     CHvvv  | 2016-07-07 16:18:49 |   NULL
     CHvvv  | 2016-07-07 16:19:00 |   NULL
     CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |   NULL
     CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:23 |   NULL
     CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:32 |   NULL
     CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 17:22:55 |   NULL

Comment: Show me the output from the subquery; maybe I can debug it for you.

Comment: I have created an answer because I can't format the result in a comment.

Comment: Just the subquery, please.  It will have 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your result :

```
  id  |      StartedAt      | StoppedAt 
--------------------------------------- 
CHxxx | 2016-07-07 16:18:49 |   NULL 
CHxxx | 2016-07-07 16:19:00 |   NULL 
CHyyy | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |   NULL 
CHyyy | 2016-07-07 16:29:23 |   NULL 
CHyyy | 2016-07-07 16:29:32 |   NULL 
CHyyy | 2016-07-07 17:22:55 |   NULL
```

The result I want :

```
   id   |       StartedAt      |      StoppedAt      
---------------------------------------
 CHxxx  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 CHxxx  | 2016-07-07 16:18:49  | 2016-07-07 16:19:00
 CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
 CHyyy  | 2000-01-01 00:00:00  | 2016-07-07 16:28:08
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:23  | 2016-07-07 16:29:28
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 16:29:32  | 2016-07-07 16:29:39
 CHyyy  | 2016-07-07 17:22:55  | 3000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

Here is the subquery result :

```
 seq | prodLine | state |      timestamp      | junk
-----------------------------------------------------
  1  |  CHxxx   |   0   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | CHxxx
  1  |  CHxxx   |   1   | 2016-07-07 16:18:49 | CHxxx
  2  |  CHxxx   |   0   | 2016-07-07 16:19:00 | CHxxx
  3  |  CHyyy   |   0   | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | CHyyy
  4  |  CHyyy   |   0   | 2016-07-07 16:28:08 | CHyyy
  4  |  CHyyy   |   1   | 2016-07-07 16:29:23 | CHyyy
  5  |  CHyyy   |   0   | 2016-07-07 16:29:28 | CHyyy
  5  |  CHyyy   |   1   | 2016-07-07 16:29:32 | CHyyy
  6  |  CHyyy   |   0   | 2016-07-07 16:29:39 | CHyyy
  6  |  CHyyy   |   1   | 2016-07-07 17:22:55 | CHyyy
```